# OpenVPN see other users on network

Tags: linux, windows, networking, vpn, openvpn

I have 2 machines connected to an OpenVPN network but I can't seem to ping or RDP into each other.

EDIT:

Tried adding client-to-client and did a restart of the server and clients, can't ping or access them.

Server.conf:

```
dev tun
tun-mtu 1500
tun-mtu-extra 32
mssfix 1450
reneg-sec 0
ca /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/server.key
dh /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/dh1024.pem
plugin /etc/openvpn/openvpn-auth-pam.so /etc/pam.d/login
#plugin /usr/share/openvpn/plugin/lib/openvpn-auth-pam.so /etc/pam.d/login #- Comment this line if you are using FreeRADIUS
#plugin /etc/openvpn/radiusplugin.so /etc/openvpn/radiusplugin.cnf #- Uncomment this line if you are using FreeRADIUS
client-cert-not-required
username-as-common-name
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
push "redirect-gateway def1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
keepalive 5 30
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
status 119
4.log
verb 3
```

NETWORK INFO (LAPTOP):

```
Ethernet adapter OPENVPN CONNECTION:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : CLEANED
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.8.0.6
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.252
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : local.domain
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : CLEANED
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.35.52.167
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.35.0.1

Tunnel adapter isatap.local.domain:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : local.domain
```

OTHER MACHINE:

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : CLEANED
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.8.0.10
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.252
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : CLEANED
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.39
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.254
```

The OpenVPN Subnet on the client side is wrong, right?

Comment: Check your firewall. Sounds like firewall issue. Try disabling it.

Comment: Worked when I disabled firewall :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `client-to-client` to your `server.conf`:

```
# Uncomment this directive to allow different
# clients to be able to "see" each other.
# By default, clients will only see the server.
# To force clients to only see the server, you
# will also need to appropriately firewall the
# server's TUN/TAP interface.
;client-to-client
```

http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#server